# ControlSend sends extra newline

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to send a text to notepad with [ControlSend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlSend.htm). But it sends a text with the extra newline to notepad.

```
append()
{
SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
ControlSend,Edit1,% Clipboard,ahk_exe notepad.exe
}

#If GetKeyState("Ctrl") && GetKeyState("Shift") ;Seçilileri dosyay kaydeder.
{
a & s::
sleep 30
Send, ^c
sleep 30
Clipboard := "`n[source]`n----`n" . Clipboard . "`n---- `n`n"
sleep 30
append()
sleep 30
Return
}
```

It sends this:

```
> [source,java]
> ---- 
> SetKeydelay, 10, 10 
> 
> SetKeyDelay, 0, 10
> 
> SetKeyDelay, 0, 10
> ----
```

Instead of this:

```
> [source,java]
> ----  
> SetKeydelay, 10, 10 
> SetKeyDelay, 0, 10 
> SetKeyDelay, 0, 10
> ----
```

Comment: Where do you get `[source,java]` from? In your code I only see `[source]`. Try adding (an example of) the original text you copied to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach:

```
append(){
    SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
    Loop, parse, Clipboard, `n
        ControlSend,Edit1,%A_LoopField%,ahk_exe notepad.exe
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a lifesaver

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
append(){
SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
Clipboard := RTrim(Clipboard, "`r`n") ; remove the last CRLF
ControlSend,Edit1,% Clipboard,ahk_exe notepad.exe
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Trim.htm

Comment: Thanks for respond, I have tried this but it didn't work. I think ControlSend cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try also:

```
append(){
    SetKeyDelay, 10, 10
    ; Remove all blank lines from the text in a variable:
    Loop
    {
        Clipboard := StrReplace(Clipboard, "`r`n`r`n", "`r`n", Count)
        if Count = 0  ; No more replacements needed.
            break
    }
    ControlSend,Edit1,% Clipboard,ahk_exe notepad.exe
}
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm#Examples

Comment: Thanks but I have still the same issue, I bet this problem caused by ControlSend because I have printed Clipboard with msgbox and have seen that there are no extra lines exist.